# element.classList.toggle() is not working

Tags: javascript, css

I have been trying to make my form show and hide when I click on a button but it is not working. I want to use vanilla javascript and have been trying to make it work with `.classList.toggle()` but it is working.

HTML

```
<i id="search-button"class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
<form id="search-form">
     <input
       id="search-input"
       type="text" 
       name="search" 
       placeholder="Search.." > 
</form>
```

CSS

```
#search-input{
  display: none;
}
.show{
  display: block;
}
```

JS

```
const searchButton = document.querySelector("#search-button");
const searchInput = document.querySelector("#search-input");

searchButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  searchInput.classList.toggle("show");
})
```

```js
const searchButton = document.querySelector("#search-button");
const searchInput = document.querySelector("#search-input");

searchButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  searchInput.classList.toggle("show");
})
```

```css
#search-input {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="search-button" class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x">click me</button>
<form id="search-form">
     <input
       id="search-input"
       type="text" 
       name="search" 
       placeholder="Search.." > 
</form>
```

Comment: First, check if your click event is working. And put the <i> tag inside a button.

Comment: It's not that the classlist toggle wouldn't work, rather it's because the id rules override class rules when parsing the CSS rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because of CSS specificity.
Because you're adding CSS to an element via **ID**, and then trying to overwrite that CSS by adding additional CSS via a **class**, it doesn't work. This happens because **IDs** get priority over **classes**.

You can fix this by being more specific with your CSS selectors:

```
#search-input.show{
  display: block;
}
```

> **OR**

If you want a general solution for all elements with the `.show` class, you can do it by giving `#search-input` a class of "hide" and just give the `.hide` class the `display: none` property:

**HTML**

```
<form id="search-form">
     <input
       id="search-input"
       type="text" 
       name="search" 
       placeholder="Search.." class="hide"> 
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide {
   display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

You can calculate CSS specificity with [this nifty tool](https://www.codecaptain.io/tools/css-specificity-calculator).

Answer (score 6):

[CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

ID has greater specificity than a class. You would see it in the console the class would be scratched out in the rule pane when you inspect the element.

```js
const searchButton = document.querySelector("#search-button");
const searchInput = document.querySelector("#search-input");

searchButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  searchInput.classList.toggle("show");
})
```

```css
#search-input{
  display: none;
}
#search-input.show{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i id="search-button"class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
<form id="search-form">
     <input id="search-input" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.."> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening since in CSS `#id` style is given higher priority than a `.class`. You can fix this by adding `!important` to the `.show` style like:

DEMO:

```js
const searchButton = document.querySelector("#search-button");
const searchInput = document.querySelector("#search-input");

searchButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  searchInput.classList.toggle("show");
})
```

```css
#search-input {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css"/>
<i id="search-button" class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
<form id="search-form">
  <input id="search-input" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</form>
```

> `!important` - it means, essentially, what it says; that '*this* is important, ignore subsequent rules, and any usual specificity issues, apply *this* rule!'

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the problem caused because of `id` vs `class` priority in css.
I think you can manage this with only a hide class and toggle it.
An alternative solution is like following:

```js
const searchButton = document.querySelector("#search-button");
const searchInput = document.querySelector("#search-input");

searchButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  searchInput.classList.toggle("hide");
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<i id="search-button" class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x">Click here to Hide </i>
<form id="search-form">
  <input id="search-input" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</form>
```